# Is there a simple way to draw a gradient in love2d?

Tags: opengl, gradient, love2d

I'm relatively new to love2d and was wondering if there is a simple way to draw a linear gradient without using an image.  I'm trying to draw a scene that is at dusk, and want a subtle gradient from the top of the background to the bottom, but creating an image large enough to fill the background seems like it would be too large.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Although I can't determine a way to do it from the love2D API, you would do it in OpenGL by setting the vertex colours of a quad (so lower vertices would be set to black and upper vertices to blue, for instance).

Answer (score 2):

Try using an image which is 1px wide by the height needed, and repeat it horizontally like so:

```
-- load
bgImage = love.graphics.newImage('gradient.png')
bgImage:setWrap('repeat', 'clamp')
bgQuad = love.graphics.newQuad(
    0, 0,
    WIDTH, bgImage:getHeight(),
    bgImage:getWidth(), bgImage:getHeight()
)

-- draw
love.graphics.drawq(bgImage, bgQuad, X, Y)
```

Replace X, Y, and WIDTH with the values you need. Using a [quad](https://love2d.org/wiki/love.graphics.newQuad) here allows Löve to handle the horizontal repeat for really fast drawing.

(Hopefully this works, I haven't tested it.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about the size of the image and the performance, the best way is making an image with 1 x n pixels, where n is the number of colors on the gradient.
for example, if you want an vertical background-gradient with 2 colors:

love.graphics.draw(img,0,0,0,love.graphics.getWidth(),love.graphics.getHeight()/2)

:)